# LdrLoadDll Crash

Tags: c, winapi

I need to load a library via ntdll's `LdrLoadDll` function, in this case the library I am loading is user32.dll. However, when I try to load user32.dll, an access violation exception is thrown on the call(last line). I am unsure what the cause of this error could be. Am I creating the unicode string incorrectly?

```
typedef (__stdcall *LdrLoadDll)(
    IN PWCHAR               PathToFile OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG                Flags OPTIONAL,
    IN PUNICODE_STRING      ModuleFileName,
    OUT PHANDLE             ModuleHandle);
LdrLoadDll LdrLoadDllStruct = (LdrLoadDll)GetProcAddress(ntdllHandle, "LdrLoadDll");

typedef (__stdcall *RtlInitUnicodeString)(
    PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString,
    PCWSTR          SourceString);
RtlInitUnicodeString RtlInitUnicodeStringStruct = (RtlInitUnicodeString)GetProcAddress(ntdllHandle, "RtlInitUnicodeString");

HMODULE hModule = 0;
UNICODE_STRING unicodestring;
RtlInitUnicodeStringStruct(&unicodestring, L"USER32.dll");
LdrLoadDllStruct(NULL, NULL, &unicodestring, &hModule);
```

Comment: simply use debugger and see

Comment: I am surprised if it will even compiles with Visual Studio, at-least I doubt it would without disabling warnings at the least.

Comment: And you can't use LoadLibrary like a normal person because?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how do you run the program's output?  Is it a driver you're trying to write? Aren't you able to debug your program (true, in that case it will run under "normal" conditions, and probably the error won't be reproducible)? Note: set your 2nd argument to **_0_** instead of `NULL` (definitely not the crash cause, just for clarity).

Comment: Did you check the result of calling `GetProcAddress()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, some code that (a) actually compiles, and (b) works.  Please excuse the (ahem) error handling:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <subauth.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib, "ntdll.lib")

typedef void (__stdcall *LdrLoadDll) (
    IN PWCHAR               PathToFile OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG                Flags OPTIONAL,
    IN PUNICODE_STRING      ModuleFileName,
    OUT HMODULE *           ModuleHandle);

typedef void (__stdcall *RtlInitUnicodeString)(
    PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString,
    PCWSTR          SourceString);

int main ()
{
    HMODULE ntdllHandle = LoadLibrary (L"ntdll.dll");
    assert (ntdllHandle);

    LdrLoadDll LdrLoadDllStruct = (LdrLoadDll) GetProcAddress (ntdllHandle, "LdrLoadDll");
    assert (LdrLoadDllStruct);
    RtlInitUnicodeString RtlInitUnicodeStringStruct = (RtlInitUnicodeString) GetProcAddress (ntdllHandle, "RtlInitUnicodeString");
    assert (RtlInitUnicodeStringStruct);

    HMODULE hModule = 0;
    UNICODE_STRING unicodestring;
    RtlInitUnicodeStringStruct (&unicodestring, L"USER32.dll");
    LdrLoadDllStruct (NULL, 0, &unicodestring, &hModule);
    std::cout << hModule << "\n";
}
```

Output (on my machine, 64 bit build):

```
00007FFF17C20000
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/KCUV42565).

And yet ... just what *is* wrong with using `LoadLibrary()`?